# Derivatives of vector functions

Tags: vector-analysis

> Draw the planar curve:
>
> $$\begin{align}
> r(t) &= \langle 2\cos(​t) + ​1 ,\,  - 2\sin(​t) +​ 3  \rangle \quad\text{for }0 < t < \pi\\
> r’ (t) &= \langle - 2\sin(​t) ,\, - 2\cos(​t) \rangle\\
> r’ (t) &= \langle - 0.1 ,\, - 2 \rangle
> \end{align}$$

The curve is an ellipse but is it a circle?

I’m guessing it’s easier to plug in t values to determine $x$ and $y$ values

Comment: What is the equation of this curve?

Comment: [Please use MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). I don't even know whether the cap on $t$ is $\pi e$ or $\pi$.

Comment: I’m thinking it’s ::: (x/2)^2 + 1 ,  (x/2)^2 + 1 = 1

Answer (score 0):

Since $(x-1)^2+(y-3)^2=2^2$, it's a centre-$(1,\,3)$ radius-$2$ circle - well, a semicircular arc, if we're restricted to $t\in(0,\,\pi)$ rather than $[0,\,2\pi)$.